# React: reset password send email with reset password link to reset the password

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a `forgot password` component which has an `email field`. The user will enter his email. Now, this component should send a `password reset email` to that entered email.

The user will then click on that email link in his mail client which will redirect the user to another `password reset page` where the user will enter his `email`, `new-password`, and `confirm password`.

how do I achieve this? So far, I have just able to create a `forgot password` page. Not sure, how to proceed.

`Code for my forgot password`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import { Button, Form, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon } from "reactstrap";

const ResetPassword = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const history = useHistory();

  const validateForm = () => {
    return email.length > 0;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (

      <div className="password-reset">
        <div className="password-reset-form-container">

          <div className="content">
            <Form className="password-reset-form">
              <h3 className="form-title">Password Reset</h3>
              <InputGroup>
                <InputGroupAddon
                  className="input-group-addon"
                  addonType="prepend"
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
                </InputGroupAddon>
                <Input
                  autoFocus
                  type="email"
                  aria-label="Username"
                  aria-describedby="username"
                  aria-invalid="false"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
              </InputGroup>

              <div className="form-actions">
                <Button
                  className="pull-left"
                  block
                  bssize="small"
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={() => history.push("/")}
                >
                  Cancel
                </Button>

                <Button
                  className="pull-right"
                  block
                  bssize="small"
                  disabled={!validateForm()}
                  type="submit"
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                >
                  Reset
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResetPassword;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement this kind of logic, all you need is a mailing service, to send email to client's email address, and in it, you can supply the `forgot password page` page/Url for client to submit new password.

And there's a open source project that can auto send email and serve the purpose: go take a look at [Nodemailer doc](https://nodemailer.com/about/) or their [github repo](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/)

Youtuber Ben has a section of video specifically solves this problem: [Fullstack React GraphQL TypeScript Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ypD7qv3Z8&t=15154s)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an API endpoint that takes care of handling the process of sending a mail to the user related to the email.

The backend will provide a frontend link like http://localhost:3000/resetPassword/token

The token should be generated in the backend which will be sent back again with the new user password

Answer (score 1):

When the backend gives you frontend route something like: http://localhost:3000/resetPassword/resetToken add below line in your routes.

```
<Route exact path="/resetPassword/:resetToken" component={ResetPassword} />
```